# Get the currently logged in Django user in a models.py file?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a model that's stores basic information about an Article also store the name of the currently logged in user, is this possible? or is it something that needs to be done in the views.py file.

Here's my code:

```
from django.db import models
from time import time

from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s" % (str(time()).replace('.','_'), filename)


# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(User.get_username()) #AUTOMATICALLY STORE USERNAME
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here's the function that handles the Article model located in views.py:

```
def create(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/articles/all')

    else:
        form = ArticleForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form 

    return render_to_response('create_article.html', args)
```

How can I make it so that when a new article is created, the username should be stored as the "author" the same way the "pub_date" automatically stores the current date?

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to take care of this in the view:

```
# views.py
def create(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = request.user
            instance.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/articles/all')

    else:
        form = ArticleForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form 

    return render_to_response('create_article.html', args)

# models.py
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do it in the view, as the model has no idea where it is being created from. Pass `commit=False` to the `form.save()` method so it doesn't commit the data to the database, set the author from the request, and then save manually:

```
if form.is_valid():
    article = form.save(commit=False)
    article.author = request.user
    article.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/articles/all')
```

Comment: I am trying to implement your answer but I fail in `models.py` . How can I access `article.author` in `models.py`  ?